# Water ingress in panelled doors

Tags: doors, waterproofing

I have some exterior paneled doors. We have some minor water ingress and weeping at the panels. The panels are typical floating panels in a well-made hardwood door.

What is the general solution to something like? Is the rule that you are supposed to roof all doors so water is not running down them? The door in question is of a form that is difficult to roof.

When I look at other typical antique paneled doors in older houses, they are usually set back in the frame a good 6 inches at least. In my case our doors are less than 2" in from the facade so they are much more exposed to exterior rain, which is why I suppose we are having the problem.

Comment: How are the exterior and the edges of the door finished?

Comment: Can you put a good storm door over the exterior door? That would go a fair distance toward replacing an overhang.

Comment: Any indication of seasonal movement of the panels?